# Rewrite rules, regexp

Tags: regex, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have urls like that:

```
/market-report/united-kingdom-q4-2015
```

And correct regexp for that in rewrite rules (wordpress) is:

```
market-report/([^/]+)(?:/([0-9]+))?/?$
```

Now I need correct regexp for urls like that:

```
/market-report/united-kingdom-q4-2015/vendor/google-analytics
```

I have tried something like this but sadly is not correct :-(

```
market-report/([^/]+)(?:/([0-9]+))/([^/]+)/([^/]+)?/?$
```

Comment: And "is not correct" means what exactly?

Comment: It doesnt "catch" my url in wordpress rewrite rules inspector.

Comment: Okay, so what exactly do you want to "catch" ?

Comment: Urls looking like this one I have posted with vendor and google-analytics part.